# How to programmatically show next view in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I created a ViewPager and everything is working fine, however I want to have a previous next button outside of ViewPager which can be used to navigate inside ViewPager. How can I go to next Item on ViewPager without swiping manually?

Comment: Doesn't this work viewpager.setCurrentItem(int index); ?

Comment: it did , I suppose this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change ViewPager's page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424562/how-to-change-viewpagers-page)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

As blessenm answered `viewpager.setCurrentItem(int index)` is the way to go.

Comment: Unfortunately I do get different behavior, when the user swipes manually and when I jump using setCurrentItem. The order of calls is reversed. When I swipe, it first calls OnPageChangeListener#onPageSelected and then it calls setUserVisibleHint in the fragments. If I use setCurrentItem, it first calls setUserVisibleHint in the fragments and then it calls OnPageChangeListener#onPageSelected, which really is a problem in my case :/ so I was hoping to find a way to keep the natural behavior but still programmtically move to another page.

Comment: @Vaibhav what if I want to show the next view of activity

Comment: @AgentKnopf Did you manage to find a solution for this issue ? I also see this weird behavior but can't find a way to keep the flow of the regular swipe when I programmatically switch to the next/prev fragment.

Comment: @Gil I am afraid not - i removed the programmatical changing of the current view and just allowed swiping. However we completely changed the implementation later so I didn't pursue this issue any further.

Answer (score 118):

A complete implementation just for completeness:

```
public void MoveNext(View view) {
    //it doesn't matter if you're already in the last item
    pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
}

public void MovePrevious(View view) {
    //it doesn't matter if you're already in the first item
    pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
}
```

Comment: You might need it.
For instance, if the change is triggered by a click, you could use `(nextBt.getId() == view.id)` to know what caused it

Comment: @Sagar he might have set the click listener of button in xml, in that case you must have the view parameter, even if you don't need it.

Comment: page swiping animation not coming?

Answer (score 19):

Easiest way is:

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener { pager.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT) }
prevButton.setOnClickListener { pager.arrowScroll(View.FOCUS_LEFT) }
```

Answer (score 0):

i fix it Better, ty Androiderson.

```
  private void MoveNextTopSlideShow(View view)
    {
        if (_viewPager_TopImageSlide.CurrentItem == _viewPager_TopImageSlide.ChildCount)
        {
            if (_viewPager_TopImageSlide.ChildCount > 0)
            {
                _viewPager_TopImageSlide.SetCurrentItem(0,true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //it doesn't matter if you're already in the last item
            _viewPager_TopImageSlide.SetCurrentItem(_viewPager_TopImageSlide.CurrentItem + 1, true);
        }
    }

    private void MovePreviousTopSlideShow(View view)
    {
        if (_viewPager_TopImageSlide.CurrentItem == 0)
        {
            if (_viewPager_TopImageSlide.ChildCount > 0)
            {
                _viewPager_TopImageSlide.SetCurrentItem(_viewPager_TopImageSlide.ChildCount-1, true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //it doesn't matter if you're already in the first item
            _viewPager_TopImageSlide.SetCurrentItem(_viewPager_TopImageSlide.CurrentItem - 1, true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentStep, true)`,
where the second parameter it's  boolean smoothScroll.