# How to call next pages of ViewPager programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

I am creating `ViewPager` and want to call the next `Pager` on `Button.OnClickListener`. Setting adapter from the following code in `Activity`:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_city)
public class CountrySelectionActivity extends Activity {

@ViewById ViewPager viewPager;
@Bean CustomAdapter customAdapter;

@AfterViews
void afterViewCreated(){
    viewPager.setAdapter(customAdapter);
  }
}
```

Here is the code for `CustomAdapter` class:

```
@EBean
public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    loadData();   // loading data as in List
}

......
......

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    TextView firstCountry;
    TextView secondCountry;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.country_pager_item, container, false);
    ....
    ....
}
```

Everything is working fine. I can see the `ViewPager` loading the two countries on every `pages`.

I can also slide the `pages` (Previous and Next). But I want to move to next Pager as soon as click on `TextView` and so on. Is it possible to do it in `ViewPager`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically show next view in ViewPager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801954/how-to-programmatically-show-next-view-in-viewpager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! You just have to call `viewPager.setCurrentItem(...)`

EDIT:

If you're wondering how you can call this method from within your `Adapter`, here's an example:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    // ... other methods

    public static interface Callback {
        public void onNextClick(int nextPage);
    }

    private Callback callback;

    public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TextView firstCountry;
        TextView secondCountry;

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.country_pager_item, container, false);

        secondCountry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (callback != null){
                        callback.onNextClick(2);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

and in your activity:

```
@AfterViews
void afterViewCreated(){
    customAdapter.setCallback(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onNextClick(int nextPage) {
           viewPager.setCurrentItem(nextPage);
        }
    });
    viewPager.setAdapter(customAdapter);
  }
}
```

Comment: oops! I just updated the questions :)
BTW Where do I need to call this method? in `OnClickListner` ?

Comment: :D yep, in `OnClickListener` of your `TextView`

Comment: I was also thinking about this but there is no Instance available of `viewPager` in `CustomAdapter ` class. Any though on this?

Comment: I added a simple callback mechanism. Look through it and adjust to your needs. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
// replace 1 by the page you want 
      yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
   }
});
```

if the button is inside Fragment then
create an interface in your first fragment when you click the button call the interface ,implement it in your mainactivity and there you set the view pager page

```
yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
```