# how put an activity in a fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

how can i put an activity into a fragment?
Please help me!
i think that i make a little mistake.....i think ...................

This is my code for your perusal. Thank you in advance!

I have this code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main extends ActionBarActivity implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        displayPlanetList();


    }

    private void displayPlanetList() {

        planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.add(new Planet("Margherita", 6, "€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Diavola", 7,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Bufalina", 5,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Marinara", 5,"€"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Viennese", 4,"€"));

        plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, this);
        lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                            + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        }

    }
    public void showResult(View v) {
        String result = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount=0;

        for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.selected){
                result += "\n" + p.name+" "+p.distance+"€"+"q.tà :"+p.getQuantità();
                //if (p.quantità.equals("") && p.quantità.equals(null) ){
                System.out.println("leggo questo record:"+p.name + " " + p.distance + " " + p.quantità );

                System.out.println("leggo questo p.getquatità :"+p.quantità );
                //}
                //else{
                    System.out.println("leggo questo in p.quantità: "+p.getQuantità());
                    int quantitaInt= Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità() );
                    totalAmount+=p.distance * quantitaInt;
                //}
            }
        }
//      Toast.makeText(this, result+"\n"+"Total Amount:="+totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Integer.toString(totalAmount);
        Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("NomeDati1", result);
        i.putExtra("NomeDati2", String.valueOf(totalAmount));
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

AND this:

```
public class ScrollableTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollable_tabs);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "PIZZE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(), "FOUR");
        adapter.addFrag(new FiveFragment(), "FIVE");
        adapter.addFrag(new SixFragment(), "SIX");
        adapter.addFrag(new SevenFragment(), "SEVEN");
        adapter.addFrag(new EightFragment(), "EIGHT");
        adapter.addFrag(new NineFragment(), "NINE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TenFragment(), "TEN");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

}
```

AND this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import info.androidhive.materialtabs.R;


public class OneFragment extends Fragment {


    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: `how put an activity in a fragment?` You **can't**. But you can do **the very opposite**: put a Fragment into an Activity`.

Comment: Is Google down? This is a too broad question for this site.

Comment: @BobMalooga. To be fair, I doubt you can find how to put an activity in a fragment in Google (probably will lead back to this question).

Comment: @MarcoDiIorio, what are you trying to achieve? i'd see if i can rephrase your question/ or direct you to a relevant link.

Comment: @AngelKoh when i click on first scrollable tab, i must see a list view of pizza...

Comment: you will need to read the extra value when you start your second activity to know which page to scroll to. try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android. after getting the extra, you can change the page of the view pager like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424562/how-to-change-viewpagers-page.

Comment: @AngelKoh To be fair, I doubt you read my comment. It's the very first one. He then asked how he could do as per my comment and I told him to use the power of Google.

Comment: @BobMalooga that is true. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can only put Fragments into Activities, what you want is like putting a car in a wheel, just can't work that way.

Comment: how can i put Fragments into Activities?

Comment: @MarcoDiIorio You may want to watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXpw4cEvecY) tutorial as it is a long process you have to understand first ;)