# How to programmatically change tab in MvxTabsFragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, mvvmcross

I use MvxTabsFragmentActivity in my app. I have three tabs. I use button on the tab at number "3". When I click the button you want to switch to the tab number "1". I use this code:

```
base.OnTabChanged("1");
```

It is work - content changes, but the selection remains of the title on the "3" tab.
[image]

How to make that selection of the title changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are calling `OnTabChanged` directly instead of calling something that actually changes the tab.

There are a couple of approaches you can use to do this. You can get your `TabHost` and call `tabHost.setCurrentTab(1)`.

Also you could try `getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0);`. If you are using the ActionBar (which it looks like you are).

Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522454/how-to-programmatically-switch-tabs-using-buttonclick-in-android)? It may help solve your problem.

If this answer doesn't help, you should post more of your code (i.e. your full MvxTabsFragmentActivity class) so that I/we can help figure out your specific issue(s).

Good luck!