# Change current tab from a button click inside child fragment of the TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity, tabbed-view

I have currently a working project with Navigation drawer and tabbed view using TabHost.I have 3 tabs in which each fragments are loaded as the child view of the tab.My requirement is that,when I click a button inside the child fragment,I need to navigate to another tab.Is this possible?Any help is appreciated.

Im using TabHost,and the 3 tabs are each a fragment of themselves.

Again,Im not using a TabActivity...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically switch tabs using buttonclick in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522454/how-to-programmatically-switch-tabs-using-buttonclick-in-android)

Comment: @DanielBo its possibly regarding activities ...but my chance is that Im using fragments inside the tabhost...please check...and also the duplicate tagged question have not yet been answered!!!